# I vs I will, following introductory phrase

Tags: tense, future-tense, present-simple

Which of the folllowing is correct?

> Sometimes when I'm feeling sleepy, I take a nap.

or

> Sometimes when I'm feeling sleepy, I **will** take a nap.

Comment: Both are correct. They are slightly different ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: The first is better IMO. The second has a hint that something might prevent you. "I shall take a nap" is more definite, but only adds to the clumsiness.

Comment: Or *sometimes I take a nap when I'm feeling sleepy.*

Comment: Or "Sometimes, when I feel sleepy, I take a nap".

Comment: Sometimes you do/may feel sleepy;  right now, you may be/are feeling sleepy

Answer (score -1):

As far as I am aware, the first option would be slightly more correct. Let me elaborate :)

The word **sometimes**; implies a time in either the *past*, or the *future*. (however, not the very actual actual actual *present*)

So you are in essence stating the following:

**"Sometimes *(in the past or future)* when I'm feeling sleepy, I will *(only in the future)* take a nap."**

When you say **"I will..."** you are specifically implying that your action will take place in the future. Combining tenses in this way is illogical.

You should take note that your first example -
**"..., I take a nap."**
 does not specify a tense. It is a general statement of doing an action (*taking a nap*).

**"Sometimes *(in the past or future)* when I'm feeling sleepy, I take  *(at any point in time)* a nap."**  ---> *Voila, there's no conflict of tenses!*

I can also demonstrate a better usage for your second variant...

**"Sometimes when I'm feeling sleepy, I would take a nap."**

Replacing the **"will"** with a **"would"** does wonders, since it does what exactly?

Yes, its removes the tense, since "**would**" can mean *past*, *present* or *future* - it is more dynamic that way and sounds more correct :)

*Unfortunately, I do not have any sources to share or confirm anything above. Everything I mentioned is just from my own personal knowledge, my own usage, and experience - it might not be something everyone agrees with.*

Comment: I disagree with several parts of this answer. First this is a habitual "will" - it does not necessarily have any sense of futurity (I haven't found an explanation, but if you google "sometimes he will" you will find plenty of examples). Secondly, I find your use of "would" ungrammatical. With "if" instead of "when", it's fine; but without that conditional, it doesn't work for me.